# Does Visual Studio Have a Built in Merge Tool?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, perforce, mergetool, p4vs

I don't see a merge switch in Visual Studio's list of command line options: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx

I have used diff tool with the switch: [`\diff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj874068.aspx)

I'm asking cause I want to use an in IDE tool as my merge tool with P4VS. I've figured out how to use Visual Studio's diff tool: [Using the Built in Visual Studio Diff Tool to View P4VS's Diffs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43185880/2642059)

I know there *is* a merge tool because Microsoft has to support Team Foundation Server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee341461(v=expression.40).aspx#sectionSection1 Is there any way I can get access to that merge tool?

Answer (score 1):

You could directly use **VsDiffMerge.exe** tool to compare and merge local files.  The tool  directory is

```
C:\Program Files (X86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 1X.0)\Common\IDE\ VsDiffMerge.exe
```

To perform the merge action you need to use `/m`, details syntax is like this:

```
"%VS140COMNTOOLS%/../IDE/vsdiffmerge.exe" "File1" "File2" 
"FileThatServesAsBase" "FileThatServesasTarget" /m
```

More detail info  please take a look at this blog: [Use Visual Studio as your Diff and Merging Tool for local files](https://roadtoalm.com/2013/10/22/use-visual-studio-as-your-diff-and-merging-tool-for-local-files/)

Comment: So when VsDiffMerge.exe is configured like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I4qf.png I am first prompted to close the file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3VNd.png and then P4VS pops up this dialog: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMfcY.png it blocks Visual Studio from loading the merge tool. If I click "Cancel" it loads the merge tool but the results are ignored. If I click "No", the merge tool loads but I'm again prompted to close the file, if I agree, Visual Studio crashes. If I click "Yes" the contents of the source changes, and again I'm at a loss. Do you have any solutions here?